# React/Typescript - Confused about syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm just starting out with Typescript/React and i'm trying to understand what this all means. I come from a C# background so this is a bit new to me. I've gone through a few tutorials but I'm still a little confused on the syntax of this.

For starters, what does this line even mean?...

```
type OnUserClick = (u: UserTat) => any
```

And this interface... the `onClick` function is defined as `() => OnUserClick` rather than `OnUserClick`... why is this?

```
interface IBProps {
  user: UserTat
  onClick: () => OnUserClick
}
```

Comment: The firs line creates a custom type which is a function with one argument of type `UserTat` and whose return type is `any`. Then, in the interface, you are stating that `onClick` is a function which returns a function (that is to sai, it is a callback) of type `OnUserClick` (the one you defined in the row above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type OnUserClick = (u: UserTat) => any
```

OnUserClick is a function that takes one parameter (named `u` in the type definition, but JS/TS doesn't have named parameters, so it could be called anything when used); that param is of type UserTat, and the function returns `any`, which means it could be any possible return type. Putting down an `any` is usually not a great idea, since any code that calls that function will have to cast the return value or do its own checking to figure out what got returned.

```
interface IBProps {
  user: UserTat
  onClick: () => OnUserClick
}
```

This interface means that anything implementing IBProps has two properties: a user, which is of type UserTat, and an onClick, which is a function that takes no arguments and returns something of type OnUserClick. An example (making up the definition of a UserTat) would be:

```
{
  user: { name: 'Zac Anger' ... }
  onClick: () => (u) => ({ clicked: 'true' })
}
```

Since OnUserClick itself is defined as a function that returns something, then that part of IBProps may be a bug; it's saying that `IBProps.onClick` is a function that returns a function that takes a UserTat and returns an any.

Comment: Would it make sense for it to just be `onClick:OnUserClick` ?

Comment: Depends on the code implementing that interface — if the onClick is passed the UserTat object, then yes. I'd have to see the code using that interface to say for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

```
type OnUserClick = (u: UserTat) => any
```

Defines that `OnUserClick` is a function that accepts a parameter `u` which is from `UserTat` type and returns any type (`any`)

```
interface IBProps {
  user: UserTat
  onClick: () => OnUserClick
}
```

Defines an interface that includes:

1. user from type `UserTat`
2. onClick function from type `OnUserClick` that's declared above.